# show Alert when pressing a bottom flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test, dart-pub

I am trying to show an alert widget that will be shown when the button is pressed.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AlertWidget extends StatelessWidget {
```

const AlertWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

```
 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Alert page'),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () => _mostrarAlerta(context),
      child: Text(
        'show Alert',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      color: Colors.blue,
    ),
  ),
);
void _mostrarAlerta(BuildContext context) {
showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: true,
    builder: (context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        shape:
            RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
        title: Text('Title'),
        content: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [Text('Test')],
        ),
        actions: [
          FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: Text('OK')),
          FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: Text('Cancel'))
        ],
      );
    });
}
```

}

This is the code of my alert widget.

```
child: Row(
    children: [
      Expanded(
          child: GradientElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          
          
        },
        child: Text('Create Garage'),
      ))
    ],
  ),
```

This is my code when press buttom.
I've been instantiating AlertWidget (), but it doesn't show me.
I am new to flutter.

Comment: Where you added `AlertWidget` to a widgets tree?

Answer (score 1):

add Future with  async  to   your Alert Method :

code :

```
Future<Widget>_mostrarAlerta(BuildContext context) async  {
return showDialog(
context: context,
barrierDismissible: true,
builder: (context) {
  return AlertDialog(
    shape:
        RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
    title: Text('Title'),
    content: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [Text('Test')],
    ),
    actions: [
      FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
          child: Text('OK')),
      FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
          child: Text('Cancel'))
    ],
  );
});
```

}

and your onPressed button :

```
child: Row(
children: [
  Expanded(
      child: GradientElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {
      _mostrarAlerta(context);
      
    },
    child: Text('Create Garage'),
  ))
],
```

),